# WooCommerce variable product can not add to cart using ajax after updating latest version of WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, bug

```
if ($passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id) && 'publish' === $product_status) {
```

In this condition `WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id)` getting false while add to cart.

```
function woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart() {

    $product_id = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint($_POST['product_id']));
    $quantity = empty($_POST['quantity']) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount($_POST['quantity']);
    $variation_id = absint($_POST['variation_id']);
    $passed_validation = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity);
    $product_status = get_post_status($product_id);

    if ($passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id) && 'publish' === $product_status) {

        do_action('woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id);

        if ('yes' === get_option('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add')) {
            wc_add_to_cart_message(array($product_id => $quantity), true);
        }
        WC_AJAX:: get_refreshed_fragments();
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'error' => true,
            'product_url' => apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink($product_id), $product_id),
            '$passed_validation'=> $passed_validation,
            'WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id)' => 'PID: '.$product_id.' Qty: '.$quantity.' VID: '.$variation_id,
            '$product_status' => ('publish' === $product_status)
        );

        echo wp_send_json($data);
    }

    wp_die();
}
```

[image]

I have print the Product Id , Qty and Variation Id but that condition getting false, i'm not sure why.

[image]

Comment: At first glance add_to_cart puts its errors in wc_add_notice. Can you capture those and return them in the AJAX result? (If not I'd temporarily edit add_to_cart to trace them out e.g. with error_log so you can at least see them)

Comment: However if this is a breaking change in WooCommerce I'd report it to them directly and ask for their help e.g. on https://developer.woocommerce.com. But you should ideally debug this yourself first, and work out how to include the wc_add_notice notices in your error response for the future.

Comment: It looks like it's just wc_get_notices(). So I'd add `'notices' => wc_get_notices(),` (or maybe `wc_get_notices( 'error' )`) to your error $data array and see what that gives you.

Comment: @Rup Thank you for the reply. It's not a notice. I have built a custom form to get variable product and adding to the cart using ajax. It's working already but After updating the WooCommerce new version. It's not working and "WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id)" getting false so I can not add into the cart the product.

Comment: [Here's the code for add_to_cart()](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.7.1/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L1017). If you look [at the bottom](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.7.1/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L1280-L1285) you'll see that when it returns false it adds the exception message to notices. If you don't understand why you're getting false I think you should look at the notices to see if there's an error message there.

Comment: That said [there is another return false](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.7.1/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L1031-L1033), if you're passing in a bad quantity or product or variation ID. You might need to add trace to check you're not hitting that one.

Comment: @Rup I found. the bug and fixed it. I was passing the wrong parent product Id. How stupid I'm. Anyways thanks for your time.

Comment: Glad you fixed! I’m sure we’ve all done something like that.